# SharePoint 2013 Users not being added to User Information List

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication, user-information-list

I have a **SharePoint 2013 anonymous site**.If I add a user to any group then those users are added to User Information List but new users when they log in to the site (who are not given explicit permission through any groups) are not being automatically added to User Information List. Any help to investigate this is highly appreciated.

Edit: The user profile is configured and working.I have another web application in the same farm which automatically adds new users to User Information List once they log in.

**Resolution:**

**Everyone** group will be added to User Information List by default for all anonymous sites. Somehow in this faulty site where I had this issue **Everyone** group was not added to User information list by default. So I added **Everyone** group to the site user information list then things started working.To add everyone group to user information list, you just need to add it to any SP group and later remove it. You can see more details on my [blog](https://unnieayilliath.com/2015/10/08/sharepoint-2013-anonymous-site-user-display-name/)

Comment: did you configured the user profile service?

Comment: Yes User Profile service is configured and incremental sync job is running every night

Comment: I'm not realy sure, but what you can try is the following: Central Admin > Monitoring > Review Job Definitions > Search for "User Profile Searvice Application - User Profile to SharePoint-Full Synchronization" > Run this TJ and check User Information List....  But I'm not sure, if persons will be created or just updated :/

Comment: It looks like normal behaviour. If users are not given permissions, I don't think they should be created in the user list. do users log on? Do they have their name written in the welcome control?

Comment: Yes that is the root issue.When the users logon to the site, instead of their display name , it shows LoginName . The display name will be shown only if the user is added to user information list of the site